# How to nicely plot a permutation matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, combinatorics

I have a string of letters:

`x <- c("a","o","s","d", "#")`

(# meaning beginning or end)

and a vector of english words:

`engl <- c("#so#", "#sad#", "#do#", "#as#", "#Dads#", "#do#")`

we can creat a matrix of all possible combinations of the letters in `x` like this:

`df <- as.data.frame(outer(x, x, FUN = paste0))
dimnames(df) <- list(x, x)`

df:

`aa  ao  as  ad  a#
oa  oo  os  od  o#
sa  so  ss  sd  s#
da  do  ds  dd  d#`
#a `#o #s  #d  ##`

Lets assume I want to know how often each of these combinations occurs in english by searching vector engl and filling the dataframe df with the distribution, answering the question column or row-wise "what is the percentage of the distribution of d":

So in the case given here, we would have

`0 0 1 2 0
0 0 0 0 2
1 0 0 0 3
1 2 1 0 1
2 0 1 3 0`

How can I go about this, as str_count doesn't work with matrixes?

In a next step I would want to display the matrix in a heatmap-like fashion,

Comment: Note that that is not a permutation matrix.

Comment: Is it not? How do you call such a matrix then?

Comment: A permutation matrix is formed by taking an identity matrix and either permuting its rows or else its columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the matrix of pairs `m`. Then create an array `a` of counts and a heatmap.  No packages are used.

```
m <- outer(x, x, paste0)
a <- array(colSums(sapply(m, grepl, engl)), dim = dim(m), dimnames = list(x,x))
heatmap(a)
```

[image: screenshot]